# How to open an eclipse view to Right Side Only

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse view and whenever I open that view, I want it to default open in Right Side of the eclipse.
How to make this possible

Comment: drag & drop the view you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while being in an eclipse perspective place the views in the locations you want. After exiting and reopening eclipse the views will remain in the positions you placed them in the respective perspective.

Comment: How to set the eclipse perspective view location.please state me any command for that

Comment: Top right of the editor there is an icon to see the perspectives. You can also access them through: Window > Open Perspective

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *programatically* position your view, right away when it is opened for the first time, you can create your own perspective, adn in that perspective you either include the view in the desired location, or you include a placeholder to define where the view should appear as soon as it's opened. See API for `org.eclipse.ui.IPageLayout`, method `addPlaceholder`.

If you don't create your own perspective, you may not be able to influence where your view is initially positioned. You can only manually position the view *after* it had been opened, and Eclipse will then remember this location in the workspace.